# Update datastructure in angularJS based on other datastructure

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-structures, 2-way-object-databinding

I just got into angularJS and for my first project Im trying to build a quiz creator. I want people to be able to create results, questions, answers and a weighted mapping of answers to results. My html looks like that:

```
<div ng-controller="QuizCtrl">

<div class="result" ng-repeat="result in quiz.results">
    <input ng-model="result.title" /> [<a href ng-click="quiz.results.splice($index, 1)">X</a>]<br />
</div>

<div class="question row" ng-repeat="question in quiz.questions">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <input ng-model="question.title" /> [<a href ng-click="quiz.questions.splice($index, 1)">X</a>]<br />
    <a href ng-click="addAnswer($index)">add answer</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="answer" ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
      <input ng-model="answer.title" /> [<a href ng-click="question.answers.splice($index, 1)">X</a>]<br />
      <div class="answerresult" ng-repeat="answerresult in answer.answerresults">
        {{ quiz.results[$index].title }}:
        <select ng-change="answerresult.result = $index" ng-model="answerresult.weight" ng-options="i for i in [1,2,3]"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

The underlying data-structure looks like that:

```
angular.module('testApp')
  .controller('QuizCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.quiz = {
        questions: [
            {title: 'question 1', answers: [
                {title: 'answer 1', answerresults:[
                    {'result': 0, weight: 2},
                    {'result': 1, weight: 3}
                ]},
                {title: 'answer 3', answerresults:[
                    {'result': 0, weight: 2},
                    {'result': 1, weight: 2}
                ]}
            ]},
            {title: 'question 2', answers: [
                {title: 'answer 1', answerresults:[
                    {'result': 0, weight: 1},
                    {'result': 1, weight: 2}
                ]},
                {title: 'answer 2', answerresults:[
                    {'result': 0, weight: 2},
                    {'result': 1, weight: 2}
                ]},
                {title: 'answer 3', answerresults:[
                    {'result': 0, weight: 1},
                    {'result': 1, weight: 3}
                ]}
            ]}
        ],
        results: [
          {title: 'result 1'},
          {title: 'result 2'}
        ],
    };
});
```

Now my questions:

1. How do I update each "$scope.quiz.questions[x].answers[y].answerresults" array whenever I add or remove a new item to "$scope.quiz.results"? Of course a nested for-loop would do, but that isnt very elegant.. Is there a better way using angular two-way data binding?
2. How do I represent the relation between "$scope.quiz.questions[x].answers[y].answerresults[z].result" and "$scope.quiz.results[i]"? Right now I just set this: ng-change="answerresult.result = $index" Common practice? Or are there any better ways?
3. Instead of iterating over "$scope.quiz.questions[x].answers[y].answerresults" maybe it could work to iterate over "$scope.quiz.results" and then create the answerresults array dynamically somehow for every answer?

Thanks in advance for your answers and sorry if this is a stupid questions. I just dove into angular yesterday..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved with a nested for-loop now. I dont know if that's the right way to do in angular, but it works:

```
$scope.addResult = function() {
  $scope.quiz.results.push({});

  for(var question in $scope.quiz.questions ) {
    for(var answer in $scope.quiz.questions[question].answers) {
        $scope.quiz.questions[question].answers[answer].answerresults.push({});
    }
  }
};

$scope.removeResult = function(index) {
  $scope.quiz.results.splice(index, 1);

  for(var question in $scope.quiz.questions ) {
    for(var answer in $scope.quiz.questions[question].answers) {
        $scope.quiz.questions[question].answers[answer].answerresults.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
};
```